# Photon Unity Networking (PUN) trying to keep track of players on each team

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

What i want to happen is when the player connects to the room they pick team Red or Blue (1 or 2)
The max players for each team is 5, i keep track of the players by using variables such as

```
int currentRedPlayers = 0;
int maxRedPlayers = 5;
int currentBluePlayers = 0;
int MaxBluePlayers = 5;
```

I've been having a lot of trouble synchronizing this over the network..
currently what i'm doing is when you join the Room you spawn a GameManagerObject for yourself using PhotonNetwork.Instantiate.
Assuming you are the first to join the server, the variables currentRedPlayers and currentBluePlayers will be set to 0. then when you pick a team (lets say you pick red team)
currentRedPlayers will jump to 1, so the 4 variables will look like this.

```
currentRedPlayers = 1;
maxRedPlayers = 5;
currentBluePlayers = 0;
MaxBluePlayers = 5;
```

this works.

Now say a second player joins and they choose the blue team, their variables will be

```
currentRedPlayers = 0;
maxRedPlayers = 5;
currentBluePlayers = 1;
maxBluePlayers = 5;
```

My way of trying to get the two clients to update each others GameManagerObject's was to add a photon view and have it observe the object's script "GameManager"
this is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentRedPlayers = 0;
    public int maxRedPlayers = 5;
    public int currentBluePlayers = 0;
    public int maxBluePlayers = 5;

    void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.isWriting)
        {
            //player sends info to network data
            stream.SendNext(currentRedPlayers);
            stream.SendNext(currentBluePlayers);
        }
        else
        {
            //player recieves info from network data (isReading)
            currentRedPlayers = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
            currentBluePlayers = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

This is supposed to update each client's GameManagerObject so that each one will read variables as

```
currentredPlayers = 1;
maxRedplayers = 5;
currentBluePlayers = 1;
maxBluePlayers = 5;
```

but instead it will only show their own, if i run client 1 in the unity editor and client 2 as a Build and Run, i can see in client one in the hierarchy that it shows both instantiates GameManagerObjects for each player, and it shows their right values as

```
int currentRedPlayers = 1;
int maxRedPlayers = 5;
int currentBluePlayers = 0;
int MaxBluePlayers = 5;
```

and

```
currentRedPlayers = 0;
maxRedPlayers = 5;
currentBluePlayers = 1;
maxBluePlayers = 5;
```

But they DON'T update each other. (this is what i want it to look like)

```
int currentRedPlayers = 1;
int maxRedPlayers = 5;
int currentBluePlayers = 1;
int MaxBluePlayers = 5;
```

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question but i am very much so a newbie when it comes to PUN, I've spent countless hours trying to find different ways to fix this, but this is about as close as I've come and I've hit a wall. Can anyone clue me in on how i can have each client's object update each other so they can read the current players in the room the correct way?

Comment: You should use rpc for that

Comment: thank you :) i had tried using an rpc before but it would only update one client, i then gave up and tried what i posted in OP. now that you've pointed me back in the right direction i did some research and fixed the problem! thank you

Comment: I would tell more if wou would ask lol but if you fixed it thats great ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have probably found the answer by now but for anyone else, just use customproperties.

```
using System.Linq;

public void team()
{
     int redteam = 0, blueteam = 0; 
     PhotonNetwork.playerList.ForEach(x => { if (x.customproperties[teamproperty] == "red") redteam++; else if (x.customproperties[teamproperty] == "blue") bluetime++; });
}
```